# Datadog not recognize tags in the logs

Tags: datadog

I'm sending logs to the datadog as a json. Example

```json
{
    "id": "xyz",
    "content": {
        "timestamp": "2022-01-11T14:10:58.413Z",
        "tags": ["source:apigee", "env:ops"]
    }
}
```

Datadog does not see my tags.
Where in the log do I need to put tags section to make it work?

Comment: Which endpoint are you sending your request to? Is this an `event` e.g. https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/events/#post-an-event ?

Comment: Logs go to intake.logs.datadoghq.com port 10516

Comment: Can you provide more information, ideally the code that is sending the log? Are you using TCP or HTTP?

Comment: @bwest, it is apigee policy. I'm using TCP to send logs to the datadog.

<MessageLogging continueOnError="true" enabled="true" name="ML-SendLogs2DataDog" async="false">
    <Syslog>
        <Message variablePrefix="%" variableSuffix="#"><api_key> <log_msg></Message>
        <Host>intake.logs.datadoghq.com</Host>
        <Port>10516</Port>
        <Protocol>TCP</Protocol>
        <PayloadOnly>true</PayloadOnly>
        <SSLInfo>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        </SSLInfo>
    </Syslog>
</MessageLogging>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are sending JSON, but the Apigee policy you've provided looks like it's using Syslog. If `<log_msg>` in your example is JSON, then the structure of the payload in your question is incorrect, it [should be](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/?tab=tcp#custom-log-forwarding) something like

```json
{"message":"json formatted log", "ddtags":"source:apigee,env:ops", "ddsource":"my-integration", "hostname":"my-hostname", "service":"my-service"}
```

I think, based on [this format](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/rsyslog/?tab=datadogussite), you need to add your tags between `<api_key>` and `<log_msg>`, like this:

```xml
 <Syslog>
   <Message variablePrefix="%" variableSuffix="#">
    <api_key> [ddtags="source:apigee,env:ops"] <log_msg>
   </Message>
  ...
```

Hopefully that helps. If you share an example of some contents of `log_msg` I can debug more.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It finally worked when I specified in proper syslog format

Comment: I'm glad I could help!